# Pointers arguments in copy constructor

Tags: c++

I have a problem where I want to clone of a object pointer when doing a deep copy.
like I have T* t1 and I want to create a new object pointer T* t2 in a way that *t1.x= *t2.x.

Is it a good Idea to write a copy constructor which will work like:

```
T(const T* cpy)
{
   m_var = (*cpy).m_var;
}

T* t1 = new T;
T* t2(t1);
```

what things should I take care of if using the above approach?

Thanks
Ruchi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you should write a normal copy-constructor and use it like this:

```
T(const T& cpy)
: m_var(cpy.m_var) // prefer initialization-list, thanks to @Loki Astari
{}

T* t1 = new T;
T* t2 = new T(*t1);
```

In the code you show, `T* t2(t1);` would never call the constructor you have declared (which, by the way, is not a copy-constructor), because it simply initializes the pointer `t2` to the value of the pointer `t1`, making both point to the same object.

As @Nawaz notes, this copy-constructor is equivalent to the one generated by the compiler, so you don't actually need to write it. In fact, unless you have any manually managed resources (which, usually, you shouldn't) you will always be fine with the compiler generated copy-constructor.

Comment: He doesn't need to write that *normal copy-constructor*. The compiler generated one is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a copy constructor requires a reference and is thus:

```
T(T const& copy)           // This defines a copy constructor.
   : m_var(copy.m_var)     // Prefer to use the initializer list.
{}
```

So you need to pass a reference.
If you want to copy a pointer the usage is then:

```
T*  t2 = new T(*t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not do what you think:

```
T* t2(t1);
```

since you are only declaring a pointer, not an object. The pointer is initialise to the value of the other pointer. It should be:

```
T* t2 = new T (t1);
```

to create a new object.

As for the copy, you're currently doing a shallow copy as you are only copying the pointer value, not the data the pointer points at. Doing a shallow copy causes problems when the original or the copy is destroyed - if the `m_var` is deleted, the other object then has a pointer to deleted memory, invoking Undefined Behaviour<sup>TM</sup> if it is dereferenced. A deep copy fixes this:

```
T(const T* cpy)
{
   m_var = new VarType (cpy->m_var); // VarType being whatever m_var is
}
```

This now requires a copy constructor for the type of `m_var`, which must also be deep to prevent the deletion problem above.

The downside to deep copying the data is that it increases the memory requires and takes significant time to allocate memory and copy the data. This can be solved using reference counted objects. These come in a few flavours, smart pointer being the most common. Here, the same underlying object is reference by all copies of the parent object. When the parent is deleted, the object's smart pointer's destructor only destroys the underlying object when all references to it are deleted.

The downside to smart pointers is that changing the data from one owning object modifies the data that all owning objects will see. To get the best of both worlds you'd want to have a 'copy on modified' system. This will only increase memory use when the underlying data is modified by the owning object.